# How do we correctly send data to Mail::queue()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to Mail::queue() and this is what I'm doing:

This is the class that sends my e-mails

```
class Email {

    public static function send($user, $view, $subject) {

        Mail::queue($view, array('user' => $user), function($m) use ($user, $subject) {
            $m->to($user->email)->subject($subject);
        });

        Log::info("Mail [$subject] sent to $user->email");

    }

}
```

This is the guy who calls marshal()

```
class QueueController extends BaseController {

    public function push()
    {

        Log::info('[queue.push] Queue::marshal() called');

        return Queue::marshal();
    }

}
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
Email::send($user, 'site.users.emailRegistered', 'Activate your account');
```

And this is the view that I'm trying to render as an email message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hi,</h2>
        <div>
            Please, click the link to activate your account: {{ URL::route('activate', array($user->id,$user->getActivationCode())) }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that Mail::send() works fine but when I use Mail::queue() and marshal() is fired I get a bunch of errors lines in log related to "Trying to get property of non-object".

Obviously my data is not being serialized correctly, because I'm passing some instantiated model to it, but how I serialize it correctly?

I already tried to create a $data array and put everything on it and then pass just it to Mail::queue(), with no luck.

Comment: Hi Antonio.  Maybe post some of the "Trying to get property of non-object" logs and it will probably help debugging this.

Comment: Just added a working version of it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well... Unfortunatelly I was forced to make a change on my plans of using just Mail::queue(), but still got it working fine, here is the code:

```
class Email {

    public static function queue($user, $view, $subject) {

        $userId = $user->id;

        $data = compact('userId', 'view', 'subject');

        Queue::push(function($job) use ($data) {
            $user = Sentry::getUserProvider()->findById($data['userId']);

            Email::send($user, $data['view'], $data['subject']);
        });

        Log::info("Mail [$subject] QUEUED to $user->email");

    }

    public static function send($user, $view, $subject) {

        Mail::send($view, ['user' => $user], function($m) use ($user, $subject) {
            $m->to($user->email)->subject($subject);
        });

        Log::info("Mail [$subject] SENT to $user->email");

    }

}
```

Of course there are improvements to make on it, to use Queue:later() i.e., but as I still don't need them, I'm just keeping it dry.